# Find the remainder of $40^{314}$ divided by 91.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Here's what I have so far.

$$x \equiv 40^{314} \mod{91}$$

$$\Rightarrow$$

$$x \equiv 40^{314} \mod{7}$$ $$ x \equiv 40^{314} \mod{13}$$

Then by FLT,

$$40^6 ≡ 1 \mod{7}$$ $$40^{12} ≡ 1 \mod{13}$$

Am I on the right track? What should I do from here?

Comment: by chinese remainder theorem there is only one remainder for the two equations you got and it also tells you what the remainder is or directly use eulers totient formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track. Then observe that:

$$40^{314} = (40^6)^{52} \cdot 40^2 \equiv 1 \cdot 40^2 \equiv 4 \mod{7}$$

$$40^{314} = (40^{12})^{26} \cdot 40^2 \equiv 1 \cdot 40^2 \equiv 1 \mod{13}$$

Can you do it from here?

Comment: I'm not too sure; would you try to solve the linear congruence by setting the first equation as 40^2 = 4 + 7y? Then substitute it into the second equation so it'll be, 4 + 7y ≡ 1 (mod 13). Then 7y ≡ 10 (mod 13). Then if I solve for the linear congruence, I'll get that y = 7 is a solution. So then, x = 4 + 7y = 53 is one solution to the system. Using CRT the complete solution would be x ≡ 53 (mod 91) is that right?

Comment: @user143251 53 is correct! :)

Comment: Is there an easier way to solve the latter part of this question, besides my method?

Comment: Not sure, might be as good as it gets. Certainly better than trying to compute the congruence directly.

Answer (score 2):

A little help from Excel, you can see the remainders pattern will repeat every **6** terms.

[image]

Then
\begin{equation}
\frac{314}{6}=52+\frac{2}{6}\qquad\text{ or }\qquad(314)\mod 6=2
\end{equation}
As you can see in the table, the sequence no. 2 in the table is 53. Hence, $40^{314} \mod 91 =$ **53**.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\displaystyle40\equiv-2\pmod7$

$$\implies40^2\equiv(-2)^2\equiv4, 40^3\equiv(-2)^3\equiv-1\implies40^6\equiv(-1)^2\equiv1$$

and $$40^1\equiv1\pmod{13}$$

Following your way like [Carmichael Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html), $$40^{\text{lcm}(1,6)}\equiv1\pmod7,40^6\equiv1\text{ and }40^6\equiv1\pmod{13}$$

$$\implies40^6\equiv1\pmod{\text{lcm}(13,7)},40^6\equiv1\pmod{91}$$

As $\displaystyle314\equiv2\pmod6,40^{314}\equiv40^2\pmod{91}$

Comment: @user143251, how about this?